# gVim: How to open multiple files in its own tab at once?

Tags: gvim

in most GUI text editor I can use ctrl click  to open multiple files at once.
I can't do that in gvim. 

What the gvim way to do it?

Tnx.

-edit-
...using gui way instead of command line.

Comment: tnx 4 the answers but none are solutions that I really wanted. Btw, I use ubuntu linux.

Answer (score 21):

Easy:

```
gvim -p file1.c file3.c ...
```

or:

```
gvim -p *.c
```

Comment: Weird, this is only opening 10 files max for me on gvim 7.4 Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Same thing just happened to me with vim 9.0 on Devuan 4.  It seems to be a vim limitation.

Comment: The title bar will print how many files are open. Go to Buffers -> FILENAME (see list of files at the bottom) to navigate through the multiple open files.

Answer (score 9):

gVim opens multiple files in buffers.

```
:tab ball
```

will open these buffers in their own tabs. I guess you could add this command to your _vimrc to make it happen each time gvim runs.

---

In Windows: [gvimext.dll: Support loading files into a VIM tab](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1720)

1. Select multiple files (with CTRL-Click)
2. Right-Click to get context menu
3. Click "Edit with single Vim using tabs"

Comment: The extension DLL seems to be out of date.

Comment: @atourney: The extension DLL works fine for me. I'm using gVim 7.3.46 with Windows 7 64.

Comment: For some reason, I don't have `:tab` command. But something similar exists on my gvim 7.2 - `:tabnew`.

Answer (score 3):

You *can* open multiple files in gvim. After you've selected the files you want to open, right-click and select "Edit with single Vim". Vim will initially display only the first file, but all the file names are in Vim's argument list. Execute

```
:n
```

to open each file in the list one at a time (`:N` to go back), or

```
:all
```

to see all the files at once, each in a different Vim window, or

```
:tab all
```

to see each in a different tab.

Answer (score 3):

This is a partial registry fix (selecting multiple files and right-clicking Edit with gVim opens those files in different tabs in the same window)

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\gvim.exe\shell\edit\command]  
@="C:\\Program Files\\Vim\\vim70\\gvim.exe --remote-tab-silent \"%1\""
```

Comment: In the PATH above - One has to FIX the value of version of VIM. As mentioned above, version of VIM in PATH is shown as "vim70" and needs to be changed according to the installation in target machine.

Answer (score 3):

- Open files:

  ```
  vim {file1,file2,...}
  ```

  in buffers, then use

  ```
  :ls (list), :n (next), :p (previous), :b<N> (open file N), :b [press TAB]
  ```
- Open in **tabs**:

  ```
  vim -p <files>
  ```

  as polemon wrote, then use same commands as above
- Open in **multiple windows** :

  ```
  vim -o {file1,file2,...}
  ```

  Then see e.g. http://www.cs.oberlin.edu/~kuperman/help/vim/windows.html

Answer (score 2):

You can open multiple files in single split window using

```
gvim -O file1.c file2.c ... (split vertically)
gvim -o file1.c file2.c ... (split horizontally)
```

or

in multiple tabs using

```
gvim -p file1.c file2.c ...
```

If you have more than 10 file to open then use following commands

```
:set tabpagemax=99 (or number of tabs you want to open)
:tab ball (to open all the files in buffer in tabs)
```

Comment: This works! Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

You may also TRY following by adding:

```
autocmd BufReadPost * tab ball
```

in VIM RC file in VIM version 7.X (Works for Windows 7/8)

[More Details Here](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1720)